# Why isn't Flex working on my custom landing page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was just trying to make a simple landing page with an image as a background and on that background three elements: a logo, a button and a row of 4 images (in Flex) side by side.

I'm not sure why the Flex isn't working for the row of 4 items.

Here's my page:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("/img/gibson-bg.jpg");
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.heading {
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
}
.button {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #1F4A5D;
    border: 2px solid white;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.interiors {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 15px;
}
.interiors div {
    flex: 1 1 23%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="bg">
    <div class="heading">
        <img alt="gibson logo" src="https://placehold.co/2000x1600">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <a href="https://www.choicehotels.com/montana/great-falls/ascend-hotels/mt123" target="_blank" class="button">BOOK A ROOM TODAY</a>
    </div>
    <div class="interiors">
        <div><img src="https://placehold.co/900x600"></div>
        <div><img src="https://placehold.co/900x600"></div>
        <div><img src="https://placehold.co/900x600"></div>
        <div><img src="https://placehold.co/900x600"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code shows my code with placeholders. [This is the actual page](https://www.thegibsonhotel.com/).

Both are doing the same thing.  The row of photos are bigger than the grid but my flex on them shows it should only be 25%.
Here's what I was hoping it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the width of the img tag.

```
.interiors div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```